# Is there a way to send a string to the STDIN of an existing PID in AIX?

Tags: aix, file-descriptors

To give you some context, there's a ksh script running in AIX that contained a `rm file.txt` instruction - the problem is that the file, being owned by a shared group but by other user, made the script's `rm` command to ask for confirmation...

So, the `rm` command was waiting for confirmation on deleting a file, expecting a `y` or `n` from the command line (from `STDIN`), and as this was being ran from another script, in a *non-interactive* way, we had no way to *type-in* a value in there.

We googled the different options we had, but everything our there was intended for Linux or Solaris - one thing that caught our attention was a *workaround* for Linux that involved overwriting the value for the PID's STDIN File Descriptor, which makes a lot of sense in the theory, but sadly, in practice this is not working in AIX the same way it works on Linux.

```
foo@bar - /my/dir $ ps -fT 45023400
     UID      PID     PPID   C    STIME    TTY  TIME CMD
  foo 45023400 16449852   0 11:38:50 pts/17  0:00 /usr/bin/perl script1.pl
  foo  1507590 45023400   0 11:38:50 pts/17  0:00     \--/bin/sh script2.sh
  foo 50987084  1507590   0 11:38:51 pts/17  0:00         \--rm file.txt
```

We ended up killing PID 45023400, but I'm sure that can't be the only solution when this happens... so my question is: **Is there a way to *send* a string to the STDIN of an existing PID in AIX?**

As per the instructions in the Linux forums, you can redirect an echo to the File Descriptor correspondent to the STDIN for the aforementioned PID, but that didn't work in this case:

```
foo@bar - /my/dir $ ls -l /proc/50987084/fd/
total 0
c---------    1 foo   cm           24, 17 Mar  8 13:43 0
p---------    0 foo   cm                0 Mar  8 11:38 1
p---------    0 foo   cm                0 Mar  8 11:38 2

foo@bar - /my/dir $ echo n > /proc/50987084/fd/0
Permission denied
ksh: /proc/50987084/fd/0: cannot create
```

We got a `Permission denied` error, which I think is okay considering that the File Descriptors do not obey to *ordinary* files' mod rules... or at least not in AIX :(

Comment: Hmm, is `rm` reading from stdin or from the tty for the response?

Comment: @thrig good question, and I'm afraid I don't know how to respond to it. I checked and noticed `/dev/pts17` was related to this PID, so I tried to echo into it as well, to no avail (same error). Do you know how to figure this out? My guess was STDIN, but as this is running through SSH then TTY makes sense I think.

Comment: Even under Linux, `echo n >/proc/…/fd/0` wouldn't have worked. It would write to the terminal file, meaning that it would cause something to be displayed on the terminal, not that it would inject input coming from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I think `rm -f` might do the trick for you:

```
   -f
        Does not prompt before removing a write-protected file. Does not display an error message or return error status if
        a specified file does not exist. If both the -f and -i flags are specified, the last one specified takes affect.
```

Comment: Yes, that would certainly help. However, that's something that would have to be implemented _before_ running the script - the thing here is that I was looking for a work around for when that's too late and the script have already been ran. Using `rm -f` is an option for the future, of course :)